# Как произносится по-русски слово Бог?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Слово **Бог** произносится с обычным русским твёрдым "г"? А то я слышал версию, что надо говорить с мягким "г", как на Украине говорят.

Если с мягким "г", то, например, если мы говорим не о Пресвятой Троице, а богах греческого Олимпа, тогда как?

Comment: Этот вопрос единственный у меня уже несколько месяцев в *непринятых*. Не знаю, какой ответ наиболее правильный. Давайте-ка я переформулирую вопрос ТАК.

Если я приеду в Москву и буду по-украински :-) *гхекать*, склоняя слово **Бог**, то буду **сильно выделяться** на фоне местных жителей? Или это сойдёт за вариант местной нормы?

Тот же вопрос относительно обычного русского "г". Если говорить в Москве *"с боком"*, то это **будет** в пределах нормы?

Comment: гхекайте! выделяться не будете )) в Москве тоже говорят кто во что горазд

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Не совсем так. В русском языке [г] как звук длительный фрикативный (обозначается знаком h) противоречит орфоэпии. Однако он  сохраняется в некоторых междометиях: *ага, ого, гоп, господи*: [ahа], [oho], [hoп], [ho]*споди* — и в произношении отдельных заимствованных слов, например: *габитус* — [hа]*битус*, в слове бухгалтер вместо сочетания [хг] произносится [h]:  *бу*[ha]*лтер*.

В слове *Бог* на месте [г] произносится звук [х], как и в некоторых других: *лё*[х]*кий*, *мя*[х]*кий*.  Но в косвенных падежах и производных от него словах звучит [г]: *Бо*[г]*а*, *Бо*[г]*у*, *Бо*[г]*ом*, *бо*[г]*иня*, *бо*[г]*и*.
[Произношение согласных звуков | Дикторы.com](http://diktory.com/soglasnye.html)

Comment: >звучит [г]: Бо[г]а, Бо[г]у, Бо[г]ом , бо[г]иня, бо[г]и. http://diktory.com/soglasnye.html  
  
Это неверно. В классическом варианте "звонкое Х" произносится во всех падежах. В современном произношении - во всех падежах Г. См. еще замечание про другие слова церковного лексикона.

Comment: Почему ж неверно? Мы говорим о современном произношении, не касаясь языка богослужений.([γ]/[ĥ] в русском почти не различаются) В языке богослужений - да,щелевое [γ]. В XVIII-XIX вв. этот звук  был принадлежностью высокого стиля р. лит. произношения и звучал в стихах и в церковных текстах. Но теперь норма бо[х] в позиции оглушения, допускается и[γ]. Кстати, а[γ]а, о[γ]о, [γ]оп, [γ]осподи - тоже варианты,произношение с взрывным [г] - тоже нормативный вариант, допустимый. Так что всё верно.

Comment: >В языке богослужений - да,щелевое [γ]. В XVIII-XIX вв. этот звук был принадлежностью высокого стиля р. лит. произношения и звучал в стихах и в церковных текстах.

Высокого стиля? Как интересно! 

А в каких словах? Только в тех, которые выше перечислены, или и в других тоже?

Comment: Во всех словах церковной лексики. Об этом можно прочитать здесь:
http://ruscenter.ru/736.html  §5

Comment: >Почему ж неверно?  
  
Я объяснил - и дал ссылку на Вики.    
Неверно не то, что церковное произношение устравает, а то что предлагается произносить взрвыное Г *только в косвенных падежах*.  
Либо везде - либо нигде. Иначе каша получается.  
Если спорить - то только с этим. А Вы возражаете по поводу общих материй, которые я под сомнение не ставил.

Comment: Может, Вы просто подсознательно сопротивляетесь такому произношению. [х]- по общим правилам оглушения звонких согласных на конце слова, а [г]перед гласными - это естественно и произносится легко.Но если хочется произносить [боγъ], [боγи] - никто не против,это высокий вариант,но и [боги] - тоже верно.

Answer (score 13):

Слово  Бог произносится как Бо(х). Бо(к) - неправильно.

Answer (score 4):

В современном русском историческое произношение [боh] устаревает. Однако если уж произносить так, то в любом контексте. Таким же образом призносятся и еще некоторые слова церковного лексикона: Господи [hосподи], благо [блаhо] и проч.

Справедливости ради замечу, что обозначение этого звука как h (звонкокого Х) не совсем верно. Звонкое Х - это украинский вариант. В русском же произношение по МФА транскрибируется знаком греческой гаммы. Оно ближе всего к напряженному латинскому H/h в звонком его варианте. Эти звуки близки, особенно на русский слух, но могут быть противопоставлены в некоторых языках, поэтому МФА их различает.

По поводу косвенных падежей.

> Произношение в русском языке
>
> В русском литературном языке произносится [боγ] или [бох] (в
>   позиции оглушения [γ] превращается в [x]). Такая устоявшаяся форма
>   литературного произношения является исключением из общих правил
>   оглушения согласных на конце слова. В разговорной речи
>   произношение слова широко варьируется — от постепенно вытесняющего
>   традиционную орфоэпическую норму варианта [бог] (со взрывным [г])
>   до считающегося недопустимым в нормативном языке оглушённого варианта
>   [боk].

[(Вики)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3#.D0.AD.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.8F)

Обратите внимание, что только "в позиции оглушения γ переходит в Х".

Comment: В "Орфоэпическом словаре русского языка" под. ред. Еськовой транскрибируется так же, как у Людмилы — через [h].

Comment: @Aer Потому, что в русском нет противопоставления. Но если транскрибировать по МФА, то это разные звуки.

Answer (score 3):

Как правило, слово "бог" произносят как [бох] независимо от того какой бог подразумевается. В косвенных падежах "г" уже обычное, взрывное. Произношение [бок] мне встречалось крайне редко, [боγи] - в вообще не встречал.

Если брать словари, то "Зарва" говорит о том же, что и я, подчёркивая, что "[не бок]", На [сайте МГУ](http://fonetica.philol.msu.ru/orfoepija/zadnejaz.htm) в книге "Русская фонетика" про данный случай написано следующее:

> В системе русского консонантизма функционирует пара заднеязычных согласных, которая различается только глухостью/звонкостью согласного: [к] и [г]. Поэтому по литературным нормам надо произносить голова, нога, ног - [нок], снег - [с'н'ек]. Однако в некоторых русских диалектах, в которых есть корреляционная пара - глухой щелевой заднеязычный согласный [х] и звонкий щелевой заднеязычный согласный γ, эти слова произносятся как γолова, но γа, но[х], [с'н'ех]. Влияние этого произношения благодаря старомосковским орфоэпическим нормам до сих пор прослеживается в отдельных словах русского литературного языка (преимущественно церковного характера): старшее поколение русскоговорящих часто произносит бога [б'оγа]- бог[бох], благо [бл'аγа] - благ [блах]. В соответствии с этой произносительной нормой строится и произнесение слов γосподь, боγатый. *Однако в современном русском литературном языке эта норма частично утрачивается, поэтому преобладающим стало произношение, соответствующее основным принципам русской фонетической системы: бога, благо, богатый, благ. Однако два слова - междометие γосподи! и существительное бог [бох] - сохраняют старое произношение: γ и [х] в конечной позиции в слове*.

Answer (score 3):

Когда-то у меня был предмет "Сценическая речь", и преподавала нам его чудная Учительница с большой буквы (именно Учительница, а не преподаватель), потому что столько знаний по орфоэпии более я ни от кого и не узнала (кстати, она же учила нас и украинской орфоэпии). Так вот, она нам говорила, что слово "бог" и все производные от него произносятся с приглушенным "г" (глухой щелевой заднеязычный согласный [х] в слове "бог" и звонкий щелевой заднеязычный согласный [γ] во всех остальных словах).
Конечно, если к языку относится как к живому организму, который развивается, меняется, то в современной речи допустимы и другие варианты произношения. Но мне все-таки ближе классическая форма, о которой нам рассказывала наша Учительница много-много лет назад.

Comment: > она нам говорила, что слово "бог" и все производные от него произносятся с приглушенным "г" (глухой щелевой заднеязычный согласный [х] в слове "бог" и звонкий щелевой заднеязычный согласный [γ] во всех остальных словах)

Спасибо!
Не совсем понял, что значит "во всех остальных словах". Если можно поподробнее. Мне этот вопрос интересен.

Comment: Я имела ввиду именительный падеж - кто? - "Бо[х]". 
Все остальные падежи подразумевают произношение звука [γ] - "Слава Бо[γ]у", "Идите с Бо[γ]ом", "Ради Бо[γ]а" и т.д.

Comment: Теперь мне понятно. Спасибо за ответ!