# Произношение Г на конце слов

Tags: орфоэпия

Как называется особенность произнесения Г как Х, а точнее [γ] или [ɦ] (не берусь определить, какой именно, так как пока не понял эти звуки точно и разницу между ними), в словах: ***пирог, педагог, сапог, аналог, берег, досуг, Бог, стог, итог, мог*** и др. Это то же явление, что гэканье, или другое?

***И ещё***: можно ли произносить слово "денег" (р. п.) именно с Х — [денех]? Просто вспомнил, что сам так обычно говорю.

Comment: Я слышал термин "гхэкание", но не могу поручиться за его написание.  Характерно для юга России и пограничных с Украиной районов, мне думается.

Comment: Что касается произношения слова "бог" как "бох", то, может быть, чтобы не путать его с "бок"...

Comment: Гэканье — это другое немного. Кстати, оно характерно не только для юга России, но и, например, для Смоленской области.

Comment: Нет, не другое.  Если твёрдо произносить, то как раз получится "к".  Если "гхэкать", то получится "х", оба случая потому, что в конце слова согласные часто **оглушаются**.

Comment: Но есть же ещё пары таких слов: рог — рок, стог — сток, дог — док и др.

Comment: Есть, конечно, но либо контекст помогает, либо то, что слово в падеже, требующем наличие гласной, что озвончает "г".

Comment: А почему там тогда не украинская Г, а именно Х?

Comment: Кстати, хорошее обсуждение можно найти, например здесь: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/17178/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%91%d0%be%d0%b3?rq=1

Comment: О, спасибо за ссылку!

Comment: Поправлю  вопрос — там действительно не Х.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Фрикативное Г в отличие от взрывного - независимо от его места в слове.

Подробности ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам процесс обозначается как "гэканье":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, Галина!